# Python labeling expression using numeric field not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, labeling

I'm trying to label parcels from a shapefile in the Python expression below in ArcGIS 10.2. All parcels should be labeled with the last 8 characters of their [PARCEL_NUM], and parcels 10 acres or greater should also include their [PROP_ADDRE]. [Acres] is a Double field.

Instead, all parcels get labeled with [PARCEL_NUM] and [PROP_ADDRE]. Using Maplex, land parcel placement. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

In response to comments, no, no errors verifying the expression. Tried switching to checking for [ACRES] < 10.0 first, no difference. Also, as noted above, [ACRES] is a Double data type. No Null values in any of the three fields.

```
def FindLabel ( [PARCEL_NUM], [PROP_ADDRE], [Acres]   ):
  if [Acres] >= 10.0:
    return [PARCEL_NUM][-8:] + '\n' + [PROP_ADDRE] 
  else:
    return [PARCEL_NUM][-8:]
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you verify the expression?

Comment: @recurvata What is the data type for the Acres field?

Comment: Do you have any Null values in the Acres field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a few tries and some digging to realize but, as per the [ArcGIS Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000027000000):

> Note: To label a subset of features based on a field value, [create the
>   SQL query in the label class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000002000000) instead of through the label expression.

So try creating a label class for those features greater than or equal to 10 acres(SQL) then use the expression to format the label. 
[image]

Comment: That worked, but still not sure why it wouldn't work as straight python. What's the point of having advanced label expressions otherwise? Oh well, thanks.

Comment: Ya I was stumped as well

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely possible. I just did a test, and I was able to get it to work by using float() around the Acres variable.

So, this worked fine for me:

```
def FindLabel([PARCEL_NUM], [PROP_ADDRE], [Acres]):
  if float([Acres]) >= 10.0:
    return [PARCEL_NUM][-8:] + '\n' + [PROP_ADDRE] 
  else:
    return [PARCEL_NUM][-8:]
```

Comment: @recurvata This is the correct solution. Per the [help file on label expressions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000), "Field values are automatically cast to text strings. Therefore, if you wish to use a numeric value in an arithmetic operation, or when making a comparison, you will need to cast it back to a numeric data type."