# Leaving out specific values from labels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, fields-attributes

I am trying to label a field using two fields. Example: "[FieldOne] / [FieldTwo]". But I don't want to show FieldOne if the value is zero. Example: 0 / 1050 should read just 1050 whereas 1/1050 should read as 1/1050.

How do I leave out the zero values from the label?

I have tried a SQL query on the label - example: "Portion <> 0" but that just leaves out the label entirely, not just just the zero from field one.

Comment: If you do this, how will you know if the value shown is field one or field two when looking at the final map/label? Or would you preserve the slash, so it would be `1050 / 1050`, `/ 1050`, or `1050 /`? Note that would take three label classes per Alex's answer, or you could create a single label expression that has a nested if statement or two in it. Example of using a single expression with if statements at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147806/ Note you would need to cast the field back to a number as discussed at that question.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this probably is to create multiple label classes. Add two classes with the SQL query specified and then have different label expressions for those.

[image]